# In doxygen, how to have no space after a special command?

Tags: doxygen

In doxygen, a special command such as `\p` ends with the end of a word. However, how can I use this command without having a space separating the word after this command? For example, I would like to have the effect of `n'th`, with only `n` in typesetting fonts. `\p n'th`, however, would set `n'th` to typesetting fonts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `\b n'th` for me `<b>n</b>'th`worked.
But if you have a special command, that can't be written with opening and closing tags, this will not work.

In your case the `\p` can be replaced with `<tt> .. </tt>` (teletype), since `<p> .. </p>` is something different.

Comment: What would be your alternative suggestion then, if it's for a special command?

Comment: I edited my answer to include the command you used in your question. As for commands that are not for typesetting, I'm afraid this does not work. But commands like \ref can be given labels in double quotes. Then you can write `\ref mylink "n"'th` to append the 'th directly after the link labeled n.